# C++ latch implementation

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

Since `std::latch` is not in many standard C++ libraries, I tried implementing my own, is it OK from memory ordering perspective or `yield`ing?

````
class Latch {
    std::atomic<unsigned> count;

public:
    explicit Latch(unsigned cnt)
        : count(cnt)
    {
    }

    void arrive_and_wait()
    {
        assert(count > 0);

        count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
        while (count.load(std::memory_order_acquire) > 0) {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
};
```
````

Answer (score 2):

First the obvious stuff: [the real `std::latch::arrive_and_wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch/arrive_and_wait) is specified to take a `ptrdiff_t` parameter that *defaults* to 1, but would also support e.g. `myLatch.arrive_and_wait(2)`. Also, there are more member functions than just `arrive_and_wait`.

I'd call your thing a "spinlatch" (by analogy to "spinlock"), because it doesn't actually put the thread to sleep — it has an operation named `arrive_and_wait` that doesn't actually do any waiting! It just keeps loading and loading the atomic variable until it sees zero.

To make it actually wait, you could use the also-new-in-C++20 [futex facilities of `std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait), like this:

```
void arrive_and_wait(int n = 1) {
    int current = (count -= n);
    if (current == 0) {
        count.notify_all();
    } else {
        while (current != 0) {
            count.wait(current);
            current = count.load();
        }
    }
}
```

No comment on the memory orders.

Comment: Assuming author is talking about std version wihout latch, it's not posible to use C++20 futex you suggest.

Comment: But perhaps condition variables could be used. They are both present in WinAPI and libc of unix